# BAMBOO for Oracle and Oracle Forms build

Tags: git, oracle, shell, bamboo, git-bash

I have GIT repository and BAMBOO.

I would like to know, how to make BAMBOO install changes to my TEST ENVIRONMENT(database and disks).
The build will be triggered by merging any branch to branch TST.

GIT repository contains database objects, catalogue with Oracle Forms and install catalogue with script - install.sql.

So build should do two things:

1 Execute sql script

2 Copy forms files from catalogue with forms in repository to a place where forms are stored for

1 I suppose i should use "execute script" in bamboo, but how does it takes my install.sql from branch TST in GIT repository? If I were on server with script which should be run it is obvious, but the script is for BAMBOO.

2 Probably similar. Maybe there are any plugins which would usefull?

Sincerely 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

In your situation your first job step would be to checkout (clone) the TST branch of your git repository into a bamboo working directory.

The next step would be a Bamboo script that would log into your database and executes the sql script (in your working directory). This is just plain old bash commands (assuming Bamboo is on linux) or powershell on windows.

The final job step might then copy the forms to wherever they need to go.

However this is a somewhat different to the usual Bamboo configuration - Normally the BUILD job(s) will compile and test application code. This might include setting up and tearing down a unittest environment. Once the application is built and tested successfully, one creates a RELEASE (ie. a version) of the built artifacts, and then uses DEPLOY jobs (under the DEPLOY tab) to place your release version on your various test, staging and eventually production environments.